# Why use a form to display the value of the treeselect data for the first time, then automatically change to the label after a few seconds?

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vue-treeselect

The structure is shown below:

```
<el-dialog>
  <el-form>
   <el-form-item>
        <treeselect/>   //this section is to show
   <el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</el-dialog>
```

I hope that whether it is the first time or the first few times I enter the dialog box, I can directly see the rendered result tag value.I just started to learn vue, so I don't know how to find the corresponding answer.I'm not sure if the reason for the treeselect or the reason for the dialog or the backend code to return the data, which is not very much.

Comment: I tried to query the data before adding an open event to the dialog, but it was the same problem as above.